# Linux permission on mounted drive

Tags: files, permissions

I've mounted an Amazon EBS volume on /media/scientist/data1.

`scientist` is the username.

However, once in scientist, I can't do an ls command on it. See as follows:

```
scientist@ip-10-30-10-239:/media$ ls -l
total 4
d-wx-wx--x 3 scientist scientist 4096 May  5 19:24 scientist

scientist@ip-10-30-10-239:/media/scientist$ ls
ls: cannot open directory '.': Permission denied
```

However if I go in one directory further it works fine

```
scientist@ip-10-30-10-239:/media/scientist/data1$ ls
intex  lost+found
```

The command I ran was `sudo chown -R scientist /media/scientist`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You do not have read privileges on this directory: `d-wx-wx--x`.
Directory ownership does not give you privileges to read it's content.

To fix that problem, run the following command:

- `sudo chmod u+rwx media/scientist`

I encourage you to read:

- [[chown manpage](https://linux.die.net/man/1/chown)]
- [[chmod manpage](https://linux.die.net/man/1/chmod)]